# Get all properties on a class that are a specific open generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

If I have the following generic class:

```
public class Gen<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

And a class that uses it:

```
public class Thing
{
    public Gen<int> GenIntProperty { get; set; }
    public Gen<string> GenStringProperty { get; set; }
    public string NoGenericProp { get; set; }
}
```

Using reflection, how can I get *just* the properties that are based on the open generic type `Gen<T>`, specifically `GenIntProperty` and `GenStringProperty`?

I've tried various forms of this code, but I keep running in to errors like this due to not being able to reference the open generic type.

> Using the generic type 'UserQuery.Gen' requires 1 type arguments

```
var genProps = typeof(Thing).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
.Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(Gen));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the generic type definition of the property type and compare it with the open generic type :

```
var genProps = typeof(Thing)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Gen<>));
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you! `typeof(Gen<>)` was the key part that I was missing.

Comment: `GetGenericTypeDefinition` is also very important `typeof(Gen<int>) != typeof(Gen<>)`

Comment: Indeed, I tried various forms of those previously, but they didn't work because I didn't have the correct form of the open generic to compare the result to.  This requires a lot of specific parts working together, if any of them are wrong, you end up with error messages that don't easily lead to the correct answer.